# PHP long polling - how long should "long" be?

Tags: php, ajax, performance, long-polling

When using long polling in PHP, e.g.

```
$start_time = time();
while ((time() - $start_time) < 30) {
if ($db->getNewStuff()->rows > 0) {
    $response = "new stuff!";
    break;
}
usleep(1000000);
}
echo $response;
```

How do you evaluate, how "long" you "poll"? In this example, I chose 30 seconds, because... well, I can't even tell why.

What are the impacts when using even longer polls, several minutes or alike? Will Apache crash? Will my application get laggy / stuck / decrease performance?

Furthermore: How long should the process `usleep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into using Node and Socket.io. :)

Comment: I know that and I'm already reading very much of them, but currently I want to create an application that will run on any webhosting service... and that's just not possible with Node/SocketIO - But I'm well aware they exist :)

Comment: Seriously, don't set yourself up for headaches.  Tell your clients that they need to use a VPS and not to be so cheap.  You can get VPS for as little as $5/pm sometimes.  Seriously, who can't afford that?  Also this is 2011 not 2001.  Tech is our greatest asset, stick to tech that doesn't use your needs (in this case PHP) at your peril!

Comment: Yeah, after Francescos answer I think theres no way around it. And seeing how SocketIO works it's really exactly what I need. I also found a neat Bridge for PHP/NodeJS that allows me to program my logic in PHP whilst using NodeJS/SocketIO for all those push thingies I have to do... Does this sound like an acceptable solution or is it bad to mix languages in a project?

Comment: I think its up to you.  I myself have a PHP project with NodeJS/Socket.io and I do what I need to do in PHP.  If I need to do PHP -> Node, then I use CURL to hit a NodeJS endpoint.  If I need to do Socket.io to PHP then I just do an Ajax Post.  If I need to do Socket.io to JS then I'll have a listener in my JS.  It's pretty simple when you know how ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think that's also the way I'm gonna go. Just have to figure out how to get the stuff running on my machine ;D

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP script may not live that long, depending on the [time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). So, be sure to (re)set the time limit. Otherwise I don't see any problem increasing the times.

As for how long the `usleep` should be, that is something that you need to benchmark for yourself. Shorter microsleeps will increase the server load, but find results faster. What is appropriate is determined very much by the rest of your application and your resources. You may even want to vary the microsleep time according to the server load (i.e. make it sleep longer when server load is high).

Answer (score 2):

You can easy saturate the available apache process/workwer.
For instance if the apache is configured as show below:

```
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    4
MaxSpareServers    8
ServerLimit        11
MaxClients         11
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
```

You can just serve 11 request ad your site will be unreachable for at last 30 seconds.
If you are looking for just a proof of concept, it's ok to play with apache and PHP but on a real server you really avoid a PHP-->Apache long polling.

You need to use something likas a [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) environment for a scalable solution

Comment: So that means if 11 clients are currently polling, noone else can request the server in any way? Well that would be bad indeed. I wanted to avoid having to create a second server that handles my server pushes, but that seems to be unavoidable...

Comment: Indeed. Apache is not designed for a long pooling request. Nodejs looks like a good starting point to me. Let's try this chat:http://chat.nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

When usleep() is called php does nothing until the sleep expires.

Generally the default maximum script execution time is 30 seconds, but sleep() and usleep() will go on for longer because technically PHP does not have control during the sleep operation.

Have never tried any more than a few mins - and never had any issues.

Potentially if it's something busy and get lots of threads going to sleep - you could run out of threads to process other requests...

Comment: You could always have a look at http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.html - it sounds like it might be useful to consider, or any other httpd thats better optimised for lots of requests like this, such as lighttpd or nginx...

Answer (score 1):

#### What long polling is

The code you presented isn't long polling. Long polling is when you allow clients to wait for something, and allows your user interface to respond instantly to events on the server.

The client makes a regular ajax request. Your server code might wait, or might respond immediately.

If there is nothing to return (yet), it simply makes the response take longer to respond. If and when some waited-for event occurs, it sends a response immediately.

The client polls your ajax request, which doesn't respond until some event occurs, but when that event occurs, it responds instantly. The client is expected to turn around and do another long poll request, right away.

#### Preventing missed events

For this reason, you usually use a sequence number in your long poll protocol. Each event is assigned a sequence number, and newer events have higher sequence numbers than older events. If you can arrange for that, then you can make the long poll be a "get events since id" request. If there are events they missed, it will return them instantly. If they gave you the latest sequence number, then there is nothing to return, so don't return any response, just make it take longer.

If multiple events sneak in between long polls, your poll will return multiple event records.

This requires some way for your code that notifies an event to notify the code that is waiting to send a response. You can implement that as a reasonable-rate poll of a key-value store, some sort of interprocess communication, or something suitably lightweight for repeated use.

Your options are somewhat limited in PHP, due to its process model. In nodejs or another single-process server architecture, you could use a simple array of responses awaiting results, and call them all, respecting each one's "since" parameter, when a new event occurs.

#### Classic example

A chat client is the classic example of this. All of the people on the chat page have a long poll sitting there taking long to get a response. The page working fine, just a network request taking time in the background.

When someone types a message, they post it to the server, and the handler for that inserts a message with the next id. All of the long polls will notice the new record is greater than the "since" value they are looking for, and they will immediately send a response for all records with an id greater than the "since" parameter. Essentially notifying all of the other chat participants within a short time, without making them constantly check for new messages themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Having a total response interval of 20+ seconds will make your application prone to browser timeouts. Keep it at, or below 20 seconds -- just to be on the safe side.